# How to fix problem with version mismatch of iPhone 4.3.4 and IOS SDK

Tags: build, xcode3.2, ios4

I upgraded my iPhone to 4.3.4 (8K2) and I can no longer build my app.

In the organizer, I get the following error:

```
The version of iOS on “Jeff Bonta’s iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS  supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Jeff Bonta’s iPhone
4.3.4 (8K2)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
4.3.4 (8K2)
4.3.3 (8J2)
4.3.2 (8H7)
4.3.1 (8G4)
```

So, it acknowledges that I have 4.3.4 installed on my iPhone and it says that Xcode supports 4.3.4, but it also says that the version on the iPhone does not match any of the versions supported for development with this SDK. Very confusing.

Before I rebooted my iPhone, I got errors in the debugger console:

```
iphone unable to load symbol file:
```

Other users have had this problem with version 4.2.1 and resolved it by:

```
Deleting the folder /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1/ and restarting Xcode.
```

I could not get this to work because I could not delete the folder .../4.3.4 (8K2). I figured out how to delete this folder, but not until after I rebooted my iPhone.

Any suggestions? I am completely stuck.

Comment: Has anyone seen this? Is there a way to revert back to an old version of ios? What would you do to move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, here was my work process.

- Close XCode
- Disconnect iPhone
- Delete 4.2 - to the latest version folders (as
  shown in the other post - If you cant do it through the GUI, go in through terminal and sudo delete it.)
- Now I went to install Xcode again, but I use Lion now and it said "update xcode" when I went to install.
- Install the new updates and open Xcode.
- Plug in the iPhone and open Organiser (if it doesnt do it automatically)
- Wait a minute
  before it recognises the iPhone, it should then ask you to port the
  files across.
- Click on the project file in Xcode, and then set the
  version to 4.3.4 (or 4.3.5 if you updated) manually, as its grayed out and doesn't recognise the device until you do.
- Clean the project and then build.

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I just got this working yesterday about the time you responded. In essence, I did the same thing. In my case, I just upgraded xcode. During that process, it said "updating xcode". Then I plugged in my iPhone and it automatically did everything else. Lots of new stuff got loaded and eventually I got back up and running. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I have both Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 4 installed. 3.2 gave me the same error on an iOS5 iPad. I deleted the folder with 'sudo rm -rf /Developer/blah/balh/' and then opened Xcode 4 with the iPad connected, Xcode 4 did some magic and a message 'Clean Manager succeed' appeared on the status bar.  Closed 4, opened 3.2 and voila! There was my device ready again.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I still use 3.2 because I prefer Interface Builder 3 and to compile for arm6 without hassle.